# solving a combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics

Kelly is having a birthday party soon, and would like to invite all her friends to come. There is one problem though: her house is far too small to accommodate everyone! She has already written up personalised invitations to all her friends with corresponding addressed envelopes to mail them in, and now she doesn't know what to do.

Luckily, Alex has thought of a clever way to help Kelly out. He knows that if a friend receives an invitation personalised to him or her, that friend will definitely come to the party. However, if a friend receives an invitation personalised to someone else (ie. the wrong invitation), that friend will surely not come to the party This way everyone still gets an invitation and nobody is left out, but no more people would come than would fit into Kelly's house.

Alex woud like to place each invitation into an envelope in such a way that there are no more invitations in their correct envelopes than the amount of people Kelly can accommodate. How is the number of ways that he can mix up the invitations and envelopes to accomplish his goal.
Here,two numbers N and M are given where,N is the number of invitations Kelly has written and M (0 ≤ M ≤ N) is the maximum number of people Kelly can accommodate.For example,N=4,M=1,the result will be 17.But I can't understand how the result can be found?

combinatorics

Answer (score 0):

First you need to choose the people who will get the correct invitations, then you need to make a [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the rest, a permutation with no fixed points.  As shown in the article, there are (the nearest integer to) $\frac {n!}e$ derangements of $n$ objects.  I nobody gets a correct invitation, there are $9$ derangements of $4$. If one person gets a correct invitation, you have four choices of who that is, and two derangements of the remaining three, for a total of $8$ possibilities.  Adding these, we get $17$